# Gatsby returns polyfill errors in console in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, gatsby, polyfills

It looks like Gatsby (in BUILD mode) returns some polyfills errors. I've tested it on clear gatsby project installation. For test purposes I just added `console.log` into `pages/index.js` and was assuming that the `console.log` message will be displayed. It is displayed but only in FF and Chrome. In IE I'm getting some polyfill error messages instead of `console.log` message. To be 100% sure I also explicitly defined IE11 in `browserslist` but `IE11` should by supported by default anyway https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/custom-configuration/browser-support/.

There is the code base:
https://github.com/gatsby-david/gatsby-polyfills-error

There is YT video where I'm showing the issue.
https://youtu.be/d6w1VwDSXVs

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you,